# I need to add some blocks on New Product view Page for Quick view

Tags: layout, xml, product-view, quickview

i am trying to create a new product detail page for only quick view section, rest of functionality i have completed and my final URL of product is like

```
https://example.com/product_quick_view/product/quickview/id/18295
```

I have added this functionality as a new module. most of things are working fine but few blocks are not loading because of those blocks are define in .xml file only for this `<catalog_product_view>` page.

i wonder is there any option in magento layout files that i can create above type of tag and import blocks into my new product view phtml file.

My Class name is: **ProductQuickView_Block_Product**

Template file is coming from **/template/quick-view/product.phtml**

i tried other method like this:

```
<?php echo $layout->createBlock('catalog/product_view_media')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/media.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

and its working fine but i don't think so its a clean way to do rest of stuff...i will appreciate if anyone can help me to do this in layout way.

Comment: Hi, there is something unclear for me : where and how did you define the block which has the template `template/quick-view/product.phtml` ? I mean, did you declare it in a xml layout with something like 
`<block    type="product_quick_view/product" name="whatever-you-want" template="/template/quick-view/product.phtml"/>` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify the design of a page with the url

```
`https://example.com/product_quick_view/product/quickview/id/XXXX`
```

you should use the handle `<product_quick_view_product_quickview>`. (because an handle is always like `<router_controller_action>`).

So, if you want to add a block of type `product_quick_view/product` (I supposed here that the alias of your block type is `product_quick_view`), you should write something like :

```
<product_quick_view_product_quickview>
     <reference name="content">
         <block type="product_quick_view/product" name="product.quick.view.product" template="template/quick-view/product.phtml"/>
     </reference>
</product_quick_view_product_quickview>
```

And if you want to add child called `product.quick.view.product.child1`, you should write :

```
<product_quick_view_product_quickview>
     <reference name="content">
         <block type="product_quick_view/product" name="product.quick.view.product" template="template/quick-view/product.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.quick.view.product.child1"  template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
        </block>
     </reference>
</product_quick_view_product_quickview>
```

To display the child, you will have to write

```
`echo $this->getChildHtml('product.quick.view.product.child1');`
```

in the `template/quick-view/product.phtml` template.

Hope it helps.